# PDF_label.php not printing the same on different computers, mac and pc

Tags: pdf, label

I am using PDF_Label.php for printing labels from a mysql database.  The database is on an office network used by different users and computers. Some are pc and one is Mac.  The labels are not printing the same between computers.  The mac changes the font from Ariel to Helvetica and resizes all the spacing. Does anyone know what the problem is and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Not all computers have the same fonts on them. To fix this either make sure all computers have the same font (Arial, Helvetica, etc.) on them or change the program to use a font that is present on all computers.